# many-to-may distinct row (the last row based on the date)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables

Pictures(tbl):

```
Pic_id
Pic name
```

moderation(Many to many relation)(tbl):

```
Pic_id
state_id
date(type: datetime)
```

state(tbl):

```
state_id
state_name
```

I can have different satates for a specific picture but the last one based on date gets considered!

I have tried the following to query all of the pictures (should be distinct) and showing the state(thelast state based on the date in moderation table) but apparently I'm wrong:

```
SELECT distinct P.pic_id,m.state_id,m.date,st.state_name
FROM Pictures P
 left join moderation m
 on P.pic_id = m.pic_id
  join state st
 on m.state_id = st.state_id
group by P.pic_id
order by m.date ASC
```

Could you please let me know what is the correct way?

Should you need more clarification, please let me know!

```
Pictures:

pic_id  Pic_name
1   Test1
2   Test2

Moderation:
Pic_id              state_id               date
1           1       2000-01-01  
1           2       2005-01-01
2           2       2000-01-01
2           1       2001-01-01

state:
state_id            state_name
1           accepted    
2           declined

Desired out put:

 P.pic_id,   m.state_id,   m.date,   st.state_name
 1      2        2005-01-01     declined
 2      1        2001-01-01     accepted
```

Comment: st.state_name... where does that come from?

Comment: Sorry my query was not complete! I just updated!

Comment: Why the LEFT JOIN? Do you have pictures without state?

Comment: Yes! but you are right! After this query I need to add where state='accepted' so I guess left join is not needed, right?

Comment: You don't need that `group by`

Comment: Post few sample data for each table, current result as well as desired result.

Comment: I guess I do need it! because I have many states for example for picture_id=2 in moderation table and I want just the last one to be considered! no?

Comment: add a where clause to filter out. That's why sample data is needed. else it's unclear. We can't keep guessing.

Comment: Ok I will add sample data as well!

Comment: Sorry Im trying to add the sample data; but I could not figure out how I can format it correctly here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common way to do this is to join the table back to itself using the max aggregate.

```
select P.pic_id, m.state_id, m.date, st.state_name
from Pictures P
  join (select pic_id, max(date) maxdate
        from moderation
        group by pic_id
        ) t ON p.pic_id = t.pic_id
  join moderation m on P.pic_id = m.pic_id and t.maxdate = m.date
  join state st on m.state_id = st.state_id
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8554ca/1)

If your desired results include all pictures (even those without states), then you'll need to use an `outer join`.

---

Edit: If you are worried about potential ties, this is one time MySQL makes it a little easier since you can add a `group by` which will return a random state:

```
select P.pic_id, m.state_id, m.date, st.state_name
from Pictures P
  join (select pic_id, max(date) maxdate
        from moderation
        group by pic_id
        ) t ON p.pic_id = t.pic_id
  join moderation m on P.pic_id = m.pic_id and t.maxdate = m.date
  join state st on m.state_id = st.state_id
group by p.pic_id
```

Comment: beware of multiple rows in case you have 2 or more rows with the same date and pic_id in the moderation table

Comment: @Frazz, same pic_id? nah! i believe that's a PK

Comment: @Frazz -- Yes, those states with the same max date per picture could be duplicated.  Need additional clarification from OP.

Comment: No I need the last one based on the date in moderation table!

Comment: @Pasargad -- this does exactly that.

Comment: @sgeddes BTW date column is type of datetime!

Comment: @sgeddes Sorry I did not understand what you mena by random state? btw my date column is type of datetime! which query returns the satte for all pictures (the last state based on date which is type of datetime in moderation table). And thank you :)

Comment: @Pasargad -- that is an essential info, add it to the question.

Comment: @sgeddes I added! so if it is datetime your first query works? and could you please let me know what you mean by random state?

Comment: @Pasargad -- both of these options should work.  I used a `datetime` when creating the fiddle.  Because it's joining on the `max(date)`, it will return all states that have the highest date timestamp.  So if multiple states have the same max date per picture, the first query will return multiple records.  The second query solves that issue and returns a random state between those that tied.

Comment: @Frazz -- please explain? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd9574/5 -- Second query looks right to me.

Comment: @sgeddes -- ok, I didn't notice the external GROUP BY. It works. Sorry. I'll clean up the comments.

Comment: @sgeddes and Thanks I guess the second query is more reliable! and if I want just the state='accepted' I need to add where st.state='Accepted' right?

Comment: Your query works like a charm, I'm sorry, but I'm trying to join this result to another table called 'likes' which has the pic_id and uuid; imagine uuid is known and is an input I'm trying to join it with the following but I could not get it work   
Select case when (select count(*) from likes where active=1 and pic_id=:pic_id and uuid=12)>0 then TRUE else FALSE end as 'liked'